# Transfer audio video and data between two remote python scripts not in the same network

Tags: python, webrtc

I want to transfer Video Audio and some textual data from one PC to another. None of them have their ip addresses exposed so direct communication is not possible. For NAT traversal capabilities, I thought using **WebRTC** is a good idea. My preferred language is python and I found **aiortc**. But all the examples written there instantiate a local server which I need to access via known local ip. But I want an example where a STUN server is used to establish communication.
My target is

*Camera -> PC -> webrtc script < communication channel created using stun/turn server > webrtc script > opencv-python*.

Can anyone help?
I hope my question is not too vague.

Comment: Sounds like the same issue as here https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/issues/49 As mijime says, I think this should set you on the right path https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/pull/23

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see another issue with the examples. I do not see and example where python script receives video feed and does something with the frames. Is there any such example?